# Git init still gives me master instead of the default branch name (main) in my config

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github

[image]

I'm new in using Linux Ubuntu and I am setting up my git. I have already used git in windows. I'm trying to set my git default branch into `main` because that's what I'm used to in windows and all of my branch in other repository is also `main`. I've been trying to change it for a while now but `git init` still gives a default branch of `master`. I also tried giving it a default branch name other than `main` but it still gives master.

Comment: Note: for readability and searchability, it's usually best to post a cut-and-paste of the *text in* the terminal window, rather than a screenshot *of* the terminal window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`init.defaultBranch` is a new config key in Git 2.28, so your 2.25 doesn't recognize it.

You can follow [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/568596/612877) to install the latest version from Ubuntu Git Maintainers so *that* config is honored.

Answer (score 5):

Besides [iBug's correct "upgrade Git" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66409493/1256452), note that you can run `git init` and then immediately just run `git checkout -b main` to switch the unborn branch name to `main`.  This works regardless of how old your Git is, all the way back to the versions before the ancient ones in some RedHat/CentOS distributions.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), "[`git var GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/03194a1afa0d8dbcf3e556aa51cf9118f38efb2e/Documentation/git-var.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var))</sup>"  is a way to see what name is used for the newly created branch if "[`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/03194a1afa0d8dbcf3e556aa51cf9118f38efb2e/Documentation/git-init.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup> is run.

See [commit e06c9e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e06c9e1df28e04bbf013840c6c50ce1be41b9583) (03 Nov 2021) by [Thomas Weißschuh (`t-8ch`)](https://github.com/t-8ch).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 03194a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03194a1afa0d8dbcf3e556aa51cf9118f38efb2e), 10 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`var`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e06c9e1df28e04bbf013840c6c50ce1be41b9583): add `GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH` variable
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Thomas Weißschuh</sup>

> Introduce the logical variable `GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH` which represents the the default branch name that will be used by `git init`".
>
> Currently this variable is equivalent to
>
> ```
> git config init.defaultbranch || 'master'
> ```
>
> This however will break if at one point the default branch is changed as indicated by `default_branch_name_advice` in [`refs.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e06c9e1df28e04bbf013840c6c50ce1be41b9583/refs.c).
>
> By providing this command ahead of time users of git can make their code forward-compatible.

`git var` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e06c9e1df28e04bbf013840c6c50ce1be41b9583/Documentation/git-var.txt#L62-L64):

> ### `GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH`
>
> The name of the first branch created in newly initialized repositories.